# Open file with installed applications in Tizen TV

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-simulator

I've developed a file browser web application that lets you run files with the applications that are installed on your device.
This application works great in the mobile version, with the following:

```
var appControl = new tizen.ApplicationControl(
                    'http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/view',
                    path_to_file,
                    file_mime,
                    null,
                    null
                );
```

but when I try to run in the TV version, I get that there is no suitable application to run my video / audio files.
Do I have to implement a video & audio player for my solution?
or is there a video & audio app that is downloadable and can be used to run my files?
P.S.
I have tried this only in the TV simulator.

Thank!

Comment: Hello, as far as I know there is a native video player in the TV.

Having an embedded player is not a bad idea either.

Please take a look at the following links:

https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenSampleGuide/tizen3461/index.html

https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenGuide/tizen3971/index.html

Comment: Hi @NafisulKiron,
I've seen the samples and they do work, but I don't want to develop a player of my own, I want to use the ones that are already installed on the device. The samples can't play a file from the filesystem and the native player doesn't show up when I try to play my video files with the attached code.

Comment: You can look for the package name/app id for the native player and try your code again.

I searched and couldn't find any lead for the package name, but if you ask it in the Samsung TV forum they can help you.